# Analytic analyse of triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry

If the area of triangle ABC with the vertices $A(3,1)$, $B(-1,-2)$ and $C(m,1)$ is five square units find the possible values of m?
I found the answer to be 19/3 but actual answer is 19/3  and -1/3 I solved the question using area of a triangle formula why is there -1/3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ can be on either side of line $AB$. Consider a modulus (absolute value) of the triangle's area.

**Added**

The area of a triangle is half the length of a vector product of two vectors defined as the triangle's sides. So, for example, 
$$S_{\triangle ABC} = \frac 12\left|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}\right|$$
In this case we know area is $5$ units:
$$S_{\triangle ABC} = 5.$$
As we (hopefully) know,
$$\left|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}\right|=|x_{AB}y_{AC}-y_{AB}x_{AC}|=
|(x_B-x_A)(y_C-y_A)-(y_B-y_A)(x_C-x_A)|$$
$$=|((-1)-3)(1-1)-((-2)-1)(m-3)|=|(-4)\cdot 0 + 3(m-3)| = 3|m-3|$$
Plugging that to the above requirement we get
$$\frac 12\cdot 3|m-3|=5$$
that is
$$|m-3|=\frac {10}3$$
hence either $m-3=\frac {10}3$ or $m-3=-\frac {10}3$.

As a result either $m=3+\frac {10}3=\frac{19}3$ or $m=3-\frac {10}3=-\frac 13$.

Comment: You mean 1/2 (3m-9)=|5|?